Can not upgrade Pipewire on PopOS
The error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   pipewire-libcamera : Depends: pipewire (= 1.0.3-2~ubuntu22.04) but 
   1.0.2~1707732619~22.04~b8b871b is to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried adding the pipewire testing PPA which contains the indicated version 1.0.3-2~ubuntu22.04 from
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/testing but it won't install manually.
Then I saw the upstream PPA already contains the version yet it won't install manually.
When I try to remove pipewire
~$ sudo apt-get remove pipewire
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pop-desktop : PreDepends: pop-de-gnome but it is not going to be installed
 pop-pipewire : Depends: pipewire but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: pipewire-alsa but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: pipewire-pulse
                Depends: wireplumber but it is not going to be installed
                Conflicts: pulseaudio
                Conflicts: pulseaudio:i386
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


what does sudo apt install -f show?

Try removing pulseaudio
